# Add checkbox in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, checkbox, interactive, streamlit

I would like to add a column in a dataframe in the streamlit and this column be a checkbox, so that later I could list the lines that the checkboxes were marked, is this possible?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, pandas is not interactive to this extent, but you could write a small interface that loads a DataFrame and uses checkboxes

Comment: You could certainly store strings with ascii or emoji checkboxes as values. But as @mozway said they won’t be interactive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package streamlit-aggrid.

###### Code

```
"""
pip install streamlit-aggrid
"""

import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridUpdateMode
from st_aggrid.grid_options_builder import GridOptionsBuilder


data = {
    'country': ['Japan', 'China', 'Thailand', 'France', 'Belgium', 'South Korea'],
    'capital': ['Tokyo', 'Beijing', 'Bangkok', 'Paris', 'Brussels', 'Seoul']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
gd = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gd.configure_selection(selection_mode='multiple', use_checkbox=True)
gridoptions = gd.build()

grid_table = AgGrid(df, height=250, gridOptions=gridoptions,
                    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED)

st.write('## Selected')
selected_row = grid_table["selected_rows"]
st.dataframe(selected_row)
```

###### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since v1.23.0 Streamlit has a buildin data editor widget, which can be used to edit panda dataframes:
https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.data_editor

Comment: The new versions ain't work with Python `3.9.7`!